# NodeJS SOAP server

Tags: node.js, soap

I am new to SOAP and I need to develop a very simple web service in nodejs using SOAP for my college work. I was studying how to do it and the hardest thing to me is to create the wsdl and integrate the `soap` library to make it work.

I couldn't find any tutorial to create the wsdl or to create the whole SOAP web service in Node. So, what I need is to learn how to do these things.

My work is pretty simple, I just need to have a method that return the top ten students from my MySQL database. Anyone knows any tutorial or content that can help me? I already tried to create the wsdl using Java but didn't work and already made some code for the soap method that needs to be executed.

My server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var soap = require('soap');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('topten.wsdl', 'utf8');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: ''
});

var TopTenService = require('./src/services/TopTen')(connection);

var server = express();
server.listen(5488, () => {
  soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', TopTenService, xml);
  console.log("Servidor Startado!");
});
```

My TopTen.js:

```
module.exports = (connection) => {
  var topTen = {
    TopTen: {
      TopTenPort: {
        getTopTen = () => {
          connection.query('SELECT * FROM `alunos` ORDER BY acertos DESC LIMIT 10', (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error){
              console.log(error);
            }else{
              console.log(results);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

At server.js that line that is reading the file `topten.wsdl` doesn't work since I don't have that file. I really need some guidance here.. Please, help me!

Comment: did you solve? I found an online WSDL generator [here](http://marin.jb.free.fr/wsdl/)

Comment: @Maxxer I managed to create the wsdl on my own, but I found other issues using node like every external request is async, so I couldn't consume the data from other clients made with other languages like PHP and Java. But thanks for this link, it's very usefull! :)

Comment: In the soap module documentation I've seen the possibility to make sync and async methods. Isn't the first behaving like expected?